# How to do on demand data loading in FastRweb

Tags: r

I want to load data in one R script and then use that data to other script or till i done want to refresh it.

Just like saving data to session which can be accessible till session exist in normal web.

It is mention that FastRweb support shared data but how to implement it, there is no document found.

Even same Jsessionid is there for all request i made but data variable is not exist in next request.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in your workspace using `save.image(file='tempdata.RData')` which can then be reloaded by another R session using `load('tempdata.RData')`

Comment: thanks, but it will not solve my problem as it again take more memory and also it take time to load image which is not useful to me

Answer (score 0):

I found R package WebDevelopR to be helpful with that.
Using example-turnkey, you would be able to upload a file, and then run a single R session to analyze the data from this file. The sessionID would remain the same until you are finished. The .R file in cgi-bin/ folder can source any other .R script that you want - hence your opportunity to analyze the date with another script from original.

If you check out this [pdf document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WebDevelopR/vignettes/WebDevelopRVignette.pdf), the authors discuss other R packages for web as well.